# TImedate stamp in MPLAB

Tags: c, datetime, mplab

In my code I put a time date stamp with the version number.

```
const char prog_id[] = { __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "Foo project V1.3" } ;
```

Output:

```
11:09:52 May 10 2016 Foo project V1.3
```

This is the line of code when I was using the Freescale IDE. Due to a change in chipsets I have had to change to the MPLAB X IDE and I cannot find equivalents for the `__TIME__` and `__DATE__`  macros.

Are there equivalents in the MPL X IDE or is there a way I can replicate these functions in C.

Comment: Those things belong to the compiler. Which compiler are you using? AFAIK both  `hitech ` and  `xc8 ` have those defines.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler has `__DATE__` only.

Take a look at page `246` of [your compiler manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002071E.pdf)

To emulate them you could, I'm not an `mplab` expert, use a pre-build step where a custom little program create a `time_date.h` file where it defines those defines with the correct value. Obviously this heather have to be included into your project.